# How to denote square uniquely in Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, notation, euclidean-geometry

I am eager to know how one can denote a square in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ Euclidean space. I mean I can write as $[\text{centre of square}, \text{dimension}]$ but **how would I know its orientation then.** Is there way used in literature to define a square?

Also is there a literature addressing the general polygon shapes as well.

Comment: The unit balls in the infinity norm are squares

Comment: Consider: the vectors $(x,y)$ and $(-y, x)$ have the same length, and they're perpendicular.

Comment: You can define a square uniquely by specifying the coordinates of the end points of its diagonal.

Comment: +1 to @HosamH. However, dear OP, when you give me two points (notation up to you) how am I supposed to know that you mean the square? Morale: there is no standard way in the literature to notate squares, even less so for general polygons. Better tell your readers what you mean by your notation.